# Stack Overflow Badge System

Tags: discussion

Would it be considered inappropriate or foul play to ask a silly question on Stack Overflow simply to obtain the "Peer Pressure" badge?  Doesn't that badge seem to be in contrast to the spirit of the badge system?  It seems to exist just to encourage people to ask a bad question, while most of the others are there to promote proper forum use.

Comment: Or it isn't an accomplishment to get that badge, but a way to tell if someone asking questions asks a lot of bad questions

Comment: What is really to gain from getting the badge?

Comment: @TinyGiant **The badge** of course ;-) ...

Comment: Yeah, but it is only a 1, it isn't much of a gain in relation to what you will have lost in terms of respect from the community by posting a crap question with the intent of having it downvoted so that you can delete it and get a badge. @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer should prevent you from being able to delete this question yourself. Don't grind badges.

Just contribute to SO. Help others, and you'll get plenty of badges soon enough.

Comment: [cockade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cockade) blocker!